# Websphere MQ isConnected variable after exception

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I use an C# Console Application to put and read messages of the MQ..
When the application starts, it connect once with the MQ and then the connection should be always upholded.
The program runs every 30 sec and check if new messages are in the queue or a database(to put them on the queue) and check the isConnected-variable if its true.

- But what happen if an exception(2009 - connection broke) in the Put/Get occur? Will the isConnected automatically set to false?
- Is the connection automatically disconnected or do I have to call Disconnect() in the error handling?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you disable your network card in the control panel and check?

Comment: Because the application run on a server and if I disable the network card, many others applications fail too.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't test it locally before you deploy it?

Comment: No. There's no connection to the MQ locally..

Comment: I think @jgauffin meant, do you not have a test system that is not on the production server that you can use. By locally he just mean a system you have more freedom with rather than a local connection to MQ. You could download the free trial of MQ and test it out on your own machine if you don't actually have a test system anywhere to try this out.

Comment: I have a dev server, but like on the prod server, I have no permissions to change any settings. So this would be no option for me.. I will check the free trial of MQ thanks! But is there nobody who already know the behavior of the MQ?

Comment: Search for MQ Advanced for Developers.  It is free without support and a per-seat support license is available as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your exact question, for a basic .net application (non XMS) using MQQueue for put/get, if you get CERTAIN bad return codes from the underlying API call which indicates a connection issue, MQ will attempt an MQBACK and an MQDISC for you and will result in the connection handle being invalidated (IsConnected would return false) and an exception being thrown. However if an exception occurs outside those return codes then no attempt is made to do anything with the connection.

Basically you should not code an application relying on this behaviour, when the most simple answer is to always disconnect if you get an exception which relates to the quality of the connection or queue manager. For example, a no message available etc type exception doesnt mean you need to disconnect but a connection broken obviously does. There is no harm in calling disconnect on an already disconnected connection.

Comment: Thanks! So how do I know if an exception relates to the quality of the connection? Are their error codes between a special range? Because a reconnect when an unrelated exception(like no msg avail.) occurs would be just wasteful.

Comment: Do it the other way around - handle the ones you expect, and treat the others as abnormal exceptions (e.g. no msg avail, qfull, get/put inhibited etc). The docs talk about the valid return codes from the various APIs as a starting point, but whilst there is a long list, there are so few you probably really need to care about its easier to whitelist them.

Comment: You certainly shouldnt try to do anything 'different' for the specific ones the .net interfaces will auto break the connection for you (e.g. connection stopping/broken, qmgr stopping etc) as this is internal undocumented behaviour - if you have a problem and it is not what you expect, then close and disconnect (two disconnect calls for the same MQQueueManager object is harmless)